# What is the difference between text sms and data sms?

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

Can anyone tell me what the difference is between 'data sms' and 'text sms'? I think I know pretty well what a 'text sms' is, but what is a 'data sms'?

This question arose while developing an android app that receives incoming sms. Using the android api, one can choose whether the incoming sms is 'data' (android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED) or 'text' (android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED).

And, is this differentiation only in android api or is it rather general?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

no, "Data SMS" is not "SMS over a 3G/4G data connection". Data SMS is just a kind of SMS message where the message is not encoded as a text string but binary.

Answer (score 0):

Data SMS messages are sent through the data network, over your 2G / 3G data connection, just like all other data such as internet traffic. Normally SMS messages have their own method of transport.

Comment: Hmm, ok. So I assume that data sms are free of charge. Can you give an example of an application or a service that is sending data sms? And can I as a device owner send data sms instead of text sms (without using apps like whatsapp)?

Comment: I have not worked with whatsapp but if you have looking up for data sms service http://www.smsdatasystems.com/home/01_Home/index.php ,This site provides data sms.